# Unity .obj import is regrouping sub-objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, .obj

I have a .obj file representing a map (generated by OSM2World) and containing multiple sub-objects as Bench, Bridges, Buildings... These sub-objects have the following naming convention : ObjectName+index.
Here is an abstract from the file :

```
...
o Building1536
usemtl BUILDING_DEFAULT_0
f 67932 67933 67930
f 67933 67931 67930
f 67930 67931 67928
f 67931 67929 67928
v  -47.185 7.5 280.942
f 67928 67929 71008
v  -47.185 0.0 280.942
f 67929 71009 71008
f 71008 71009 67932
f 71009 67933 67932
usemtl ROOF_DEFAULT_0
f 67928 67932 67930
f 71008 67932 67928
o Building1537
usemtl BUILDING_DEFAULT_0
f 65093 65094 65091
f 65094 65092 65091
f 65091 65092 65089
f 65092 65090 65089
f 65089 65090 63035
f 65090 63036 63035
f 63035 63036 63033
f 63036 63034 63033
f 63033 63034 65093
f 63034 65094 65093
usemtl ROOF_DEFAULT_0
f 65091 63033 65093
f 65089 63035 63033
f 65089 63033 65091
...
```

When I import it in a Unity project, the ObjectNameX sub-objects are "abstracted" as a single "Building" object :

[image]

When I open it in Blender, I have the expected result (multiple ObjectNameX objects) :

[image]

Any ideas to avoid this behavior ?

Thank you for your help.